# Laravel 5 on Shared Hosting with No SSH: How to store uploaded file directly to public_html folder?

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

My structure is like this:

```
/laravelfiles
/public_html
--/demo
----/index.php (and other files inside public folder)
```

I have changed the index.php to access /laravelfiles, everything works fine.

My config filesystem:

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path(),
],

'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path(),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

When I try to store a file:

```
Storage::disk('public')->put($folder.'/'.$file_name, $file_data);
```

It stores inside laravelfiles/public folder. Because it is separated the file is inaccessible.

What I want is to store the file inside the /public_html/demo folder (the same folder where index.php is).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add in your config/filesystems.php

```
'custom' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'root'   => '../path/to/your/new/storage/folder',
    ],
```

and then

```
Storage::disk('custom')->put($folder.'/'.$file_name, $file_data);
```

Comment: Thank you. Driver custom doesn't work though, I used driver local instead, the rest is fine.

Comment: @RizkiHadiaturrasyid This code will work. But You actually need to change the public directory of the project. the Laravel's predefined public directory is named public. But in shared hosting the public directory is public_html. This solution maybe fixed your problem for now but you will get the same problem when other stuff is happening.

Comment: @SalarBahador I still have the 'local' driver configuration intact, and only changed the second line the 'driver' => 'custom' to 'driver' -> 'local'. So there are three configs now, public, local, and custom.

Answer (score 0):

You must bind and change the public path in application to public_html by adding this line of code in AppServiceProvider.php

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {    
          // uncomment this after deployment to actual server
        $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
            return base_path('public_html');
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a third party storage, like Amazon S3 or Ms Azure. They have basic/free plans too.